# OS Level and MySQL

Tags: linux, mysql

I've just read that incorrect configuration of innodb_buffer_pool_size can caused OS level paging. Does anyone know how this can happen and how to prevent this? Currently I'm using CentOS 4 and MySQL 5.0.41

Comment: Linux 5.0.41 -> Mysql 5.0.41

Answer (score 1):

Place [memlock option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_memlock) in my.cnf. In CentOS5 SELinux was preventing locking mysqld process in memory and I've must create my own module to enable this.

Another possibility is to use [Large Pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/large-page-support.html), which always resides in memory. You must remember to place `ulimit -l unlimited` in your mysqld startup script

Answer (score 0):

If you've got swap enabled on your machine and you have larger buffer pools than you have physical RAM then it will cause stuff to swap out to disk to free up RAM for your buffer pools. Prevent it by disabling swap or making sure that mysql won't ever eat enough physical RAM to be swapped out.

Comment: "disable swap" is like playing Russian roulette with your processes.

Comment: Depends a lot on what the server is doing.

Comment: Are you saying total physical RAM or the remain physical RAM after I turn on the MySQL service ?

Comment: when you disable swap and RAM runs out, the oom_killer will start killing process in your system. It propably kill mysqld process. This may lead to mysql tablespace corruption.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, to avoid paging you need to keep the buffer size small enough that it will fit completely in memory, along with everything else the OS uses the memory for. If the total memory requirements become greater than the the physical memory it gets swapped. If you have no swap space something has to break.